# Jackson, special relativity, addition of velocities

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

So I am currently working my way through the "Classical Electrodynamics" from Jackson and am stuck in chapter 11 at the velocity-addition formula. Before equation 11.34 he says, that the factor $1+\frac{\boldsymbol{v}\cdot \boldsymbol{u'}}{c^2}$ can also be expressed through $\gamma_u=\gamma_v\gamma_{u'}(1+\frac{\boldsymbol{v}\cdot \boldsymbol{u'}}{c^2})$, which can "directly" be seen from equation 11.32 
$$u=\frac{\sqrt{u'^2+v^2+2u'v\cos\theta'-(\frac{u'v\sin\theta'}{c})^2}}{1+\frac{u'v}{c^2}\cos\theta'}.$$

Can someone explain this to me or have some idea what he means?

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply work out

$$
1 - \frac{u^2}{c^2} = \frac{\left(1+\frac{u'v}{c^2}\cos\theta'\right)^2 - \frac{u'^2}{c^2} - \frac{v^2}{c^2} - \frac{2u'v\cos\theta'}{c^2} + \frac{u'^2v^2\sin^2\theta'}{c^4}}{\left(1+\frac{u'v}{c^2}\cos\theta'\right)^2}
$$
and you'll find

$$
1 - \frac{u^2}{c^2} = \frac{\left(1-\frac{u'^2}{c^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)}{\left(1+\frac{u'v}{c^2}\cos\theta'\right)^2},
$$
from which the statement follows.